# Converting Date to week Day name and part of the day

Tags: azure, hadoop, apache-pig

so how do i get this output from pig with the following inputs. which commands should i use

Input:

```
10/3/2013 1200
10/4/2013 0000
```

Expected Output:

```
Monday Morning 
Tuesday Evening
```

Comment: How is 1200 morning and 0000 evening?

Comment: so i have to get the output that way! please help if you can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the field into 2 fields and then use ToDate for getting the name of the day.For evening and morning,you can check the value and assign.Assuming you have a relation with 1 field

```
B = FOREACH A GENERATE STRSPLIT((chararray)A.$0,' ',2);
C = FOREACH B GENERATE ToString(ToDate(B.$0,'MM/dd/yyyy'), 'E'),(CASE B.$1
                          WHEN '1200' THEN 'Morning' 
                          WHEN '0000' THEN 'Evening'
                          ELSE '' END
                          )
```